Why a "Constant Current Amplifier"? [Opamp Labs 440c | SM-100S]
Opamp Labs (which seems to be winding down as of 2024, but is still a company with a venerable reputation) primarily makes/made equipment for commercial Recording and Broadcast applications.
Many of their products are "plugin based". One such product, their Model 440c, is a 50 W amplifier module touted to be usable as a "constant current" amplifier:
https://www.opamplabs.com/products/logic-module-plug-in/d-c-power-amps/440c.html
There is also a 2-channel amplifier made of (2x) of these plus one of their power supplies, and it is known as the SM-500s:
https://www.opamplabs.com/products/logic-module-plug-in/audio-power-amps/sm-100s.html
I am not familiar with this "constant current" terminology but from what I've gathered, Opamp Labs isn't a company that engages in "magical thinking" when it comes to audio -- in fact quite the opposite: they seem(ed) to approach it in a very sober, "engineer-like", and fact-based fashion.

My questions are as follows:

What might be the reason for making the distinction that this is a "constant current" amplifier, and what makes it different from a "typical" audio amplifier implementation (if there is any difference at all)?

Is there any apparent way to tell if this amplifier is Class A (as opposed to Class A/AB)? It seems to have only a tiny handful of components and a massive heat sink, and these things (plus the relatively low wattage) hinted to me that it might be, but I could not find Documentation one way or the other.



Thanks for those comments! I found them both to be very informative. Based on them I've come to a new conclusion.
My mental model for this Amplifier is now as follows (especially in light of the versatility of this unit to handle not only "loudspeaker-like" loads but also things like motor controls): "A heck of an Audio Power Amp, plus it can do a whole lot more things well".

Most speaker drivers are designed to be driven by a stiff, voltage waveform, that does not vary as the speaker impedance varies.  If you wanted to design your own speaker, or were into experimenting, you could instead design a speaker that was meant to be driven by a current, in which case the voltage across the speaker would vary as the speaker impedance varies.
Some audiophiles like this idea.
It looks as though the manufacturer of this amplifier has verified that it will work fine when configured as a current source driving the speaker.  Using this amplifier with the feedback taken across a one ohm resistor instead of across the speaker will convert it to a current output.  That is shown in one of the manufacturer’s schematics. Any high current op amp, when used in this configuration, would drive the speaker with a current, rather than a voltage.

The claim that this is a "constant current amplifier" implies to me to that it is designed to perform this function:
$$ I_{OUT} = A(V_{NONINV} - V_{INV}) $$
as opposed to
$$ V_{OUT} = A(V_{NONINV} - V_{INV}) $$
where \$A\$ is some large open-loop gain.
That same behaviour can be obtained from any regular op-amp, if feedback is taken from the voltage across some current-sense resistance, but it seems that this device takes care of that for you. I would imagine that the output must be class AB, since output current can be both positive and negative (sinking and sourcing), which would require some kind of push-pull arrangement:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The manufacturer provides this diagram, on its website:

It states that the purpose is to improve the slew rate of voltage across inductive loads. If you apply a fixed voltage \$V\$ across such a load, the current in that load will rise or fall at a rate dictated by the relationship \$\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{V}{L}\$. This amplifier, though, will tend to saturate its output, applying maximum voltage across the load for the greatest \$\frac{V}{L}\$ possible, until load current reaches the some target. If the load has a well defined resistance, then the voltage across it will also be well defined, so indirectly it is still implementing a voltage-in voltage-out power stage, but with improved load voltage slew rate.
I'm speculating here, because I'm no audio expert, but I've never worried that a loudspeaker might have such great \$\frac{L}{R}\$ that it can't follow an audio signal with frequency components at the top of its rated frequency spectrum, and amplitudes approaching its rated power. However, the goal is for the loudspeaker diaphragm to follow as closely as possible some voltage waveform, and since diaphragm displacement is proportional to current, this arrangement could conceivably assist a loudspeaker to follow fast transients better than a regular voltage-output power stage, and perhaps raise the loudspeaker's frequency range somewhat. Whether that's good for the paper diaphragm is another story.
The diagram alludes to any kind of servo application, which includes motor control. This approach would no doubt cause a motor to accelerate more quickly, and in this respect I can see the value of such a design.
It's trivial to build current sources and current sinks, but not so easy to build something that does both. Issues of crossover distortion and quiescent current are present whether you're controlling current or voltage, and the biasing required is challenging. The real benefit of this amplifier is that it takes care of all that for you (and the heat-sinking), in a module that you just plug in, and off you go.
